# JQL to get blocked Issues

Tags: jira, jql

Is there a native JQL (not a plugin) that returns tickets that have linked issues listed as "is blocked by" (so I can see all my blocked tickets).

All I have found is [linkedIssues()](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwareserver074/advanced-searching-functions-reference-921472948.html#Advancedsearching-functionsreference-linkedIssueslinkedIssues()) but that can require a specific issue ID to search for which is entirely unhelpful.

I am using Jira Cloud 7.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to do that using issueLinkType = "is blocked by"

Comment: This is the correct answer, and it does work, including in Jira Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

In the core JIRA JQL functionality the closest thing you have, as you've already found out, is `linkedIssues()` that requires a parent Issue reference.

What you need is [Adaptavist ScriptRunner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/cloud/overview), they have a function called [`hasLinks()`](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_haslinks). There are also a handful of other add-ons that offer this functionality but like ScriptRunner, they all cost money.

[Related JIRA community question](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/JIRA-questions/jira-query-issues-with-linked-issues/qaq-p/426769)
[JIRA Cloud feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRACLOUD-25640)

Comment: It is infuriating that in Jira Cloud, if I want to be able to identify issues that are blocked by other tickets, I must pay $200 a month for a 3rd party plugin called ScriptRunner.

Comment: Warning: This answer and the above comment are outdated. See the answer by @MaikoID for a working solution. You do not need a third-party plugin for this in 2023.

Answer (score 1):

The below query is also helpful (add it in the filter setup):

```
project = "Project ID" AND issuetype in (story, Spike) AND Sprint = "Sprint ID" AND linkedIssue in issueHistory()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's good to include an explanation of how your code answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

According to Esther Strom's answer on [this Atlassian site](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Marking-an-issue-as-blocked-in-JIRA-Kanban/qaq-p/331262), there's a new query type:

> Atlassian has very recently introduced a new JQL function called `issueLinkType`, which can be used in filters, but also in boards.
>
> It's not perfect; if you're already using card colors for something else, you won't be able to use this as well. It also behaves inconsistently when a ticket has links of multiple types. But if you're looking for an easy way to get a view into what might be blocked, and what might have blockers, it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

In KQL you can specified the type of link.
For what you want to do here what you can use

issue in linkedIssues([Issue#],"is blocked by")